# React native navigator passing parent component to child

Tags: react-native

I don't know how to pass a reference to the TripList instance below to the AddTrip component. I need to do something like that to signal to TripList to refresh the data after adding a new trip.

In my render() method, inside `<Navigator>` I have:

```
if (route.index === 1) {
  return  <TripList
    title={route.title}
    onForward={ () => {
        navigator.push({
            title: 'Add New Trip',
            index: 2,
        });
    }}
    onBack={() => {
        if (route.index > 0) {
            navigator.pop();
        }
    }}
/>
} else {
  return <AddTrip
    styles={tripStyles}
    title={route.title}
    onBack={() => { navigator.pop(); }}
     />
}
```

However, when I call onBack() in AddTrip, after adding a trip, I want to call refresh() on TripList so the new trip is displayed. How best can I structure things to do that? I'm guessing I need to pass TripList somehow to AddTrip and then I can call refresh() there easily right before calling onBack().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how React works. You don't pass instances of a component around, rather you pass the data to your component via `props`. And your component `AddTrip` should receive another `props` which is a function to call when adding a trip.

Let me illustrate this with a code example, this is not how your code should be in the end, but it'll illustrate how to contain the data outside of your components.

```
// Placed at the top of the file, not in a class or function.
let allTrips = [];

// Your navigator code.
if (route.index === 1) {
  return  <TripList
    trips={allTrips}
    title={route.title}
    onForward={ () => {
        navigator.push({
            title: 'Add New Trip',
            index: 2,
        });
    }}
    onBack={() => {
        if (route.index > 0) {
            navigator.pop();
        }
    }} />

} else {
  return <AddTrip
    styles={tripStyles}
    title={route.title}
    onAdd={(tripData) => {
        allTrips = [...allTrips, tripData];
    }}
    onBack={() => { navigator.pop(); }} />
}
```

As you can see, the logic about adding and finding the trips comes from the parent component, which is the navigator in this case. You will also note that we are reconstructing the content of `allTrips`, this is important as React is based on the concept of immutability.

You must have heard of `Redux` which is a system allowing all your components to discuss with a global store from which you fetch and save all your application state. It's a bit more complex that's why I did not use it as an example it.

I'll almost forget the most important! You will not need to signal to to your component that it needs refreshing, the magic of React should take care of it by itself!

Comment: Ok, that makes some sense. I was keeping allTrips in TripList.state. If I move it to a global then it makes it easier. However, I don't buy that last bit about react refreshing itself. There's no way for react to know that I've replaced allTrips - you'd have to let react replace it with some kind of proxy that detects assignment - assuming that's possible in javascript. Which is why I was using TripList.state and setState on changing the data. However, it's possible that navigator.pop() will ensure render() is called again - I will try it and see. If you have ideas on that front I'm all ears.

Comment: I managed to get it to work. I cached allTrips in the render method on the component, and then implemented shouldComponentUpdate() { return this.cachedTrips !== allTrips; }. Navigator does call that when changing scenes. However, I had to switch to the scene in a callback from initially populating allTrips via fetch, because otherwise it's rendered with an empty allTrips and shouldComponentUpdate() is not invoked until navigating AWAY from it.